# How to remove Excluded Changes from 'tf diff' output?

Tags: tfs, diff

To create a unified diff of pending changes, you can use the `tf diff` command like so:

```
tf diff /recursive /format:unified C:\Development\MyProjectDir > pendingChanges.diff
```

However, this will output a diff containing changes to files both in the "Included Changes" and the "Excluded Changes" sections of the Pending Changes window in Visual Studio.  Is there any way to output a diff just with changes to files in the "Included Changes" section?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the changes you want in a shelveset you can compare the shelveset to the changeset the shelveset is based on.

The updated command would then be something like (assuming you run it from the root of your workspace folder)

`tf diff /recursive /format:unified /shelveset:MyPendingChanges . > pendingChanges.diff`

Refer to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fd7dc73(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information

Comment: Mmm, that still involves the rather cumbersome process of creating a shelveset though.  Oh how I wish we were using Git repos...

Comment: You can use git on your own personal machine and push to a TFS repo without impacting the rest of the team if you use git-tfs or git-tf.

Comment: True.  There's an overhead to that, though, and we use changesets to do code review, which is a pain compared to just reviewing a branch's diff.